# Write functions to save and load an object

Tags: r

I'm trying to simplify saving and loading objects by using wrapper functions that call save() and load().

Here is the code:

```
#Just creates a file path
.z$filePath.set <- function(filename){
    return(paste("C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Computer/R/Data/",
    filename,sep=""))
}

#Saves an object
.z$file.write <- function(obj,fname){    
    filepath = .z$filePath.set(fname)
    fp = file(filepath,open="wb")
    save(obj,file=fp)
    close(fp)
}

#Loads an object
.z$file.read <- function(fname){
    filepath = .z$filePath.set(fname)
    fp = file(filepath,open="rb")
    load(fp,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    close(fp)
}

#Then run the code (tmp is a large data.frame):
    .z$file.write(obj=tmp,fname="tmp.R")
    rm(tmp)
    .z$file.read(fname="tmp.R")
```

The problem is that the object read into R from the file "tmp.R" is named
"obj" instead of the original "tmp".  It is a nuisance to rename the object after calling .z$file.read().  Is there an easy way to assign obj to tmp in .z$file.read()?  I tried putting an assign statement in .z$file.read(), but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: `loadObject` and `saveObject` in package `R.utils` provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe `saveRDS` & `readRDS` is a better choice.

Comment: loadObject and saveObject do the job. Thanks very much.